# Javascript document.cookie if statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, cookies

I am trying a implement a simple if statement based on a cookie setting. The function is as follows:

```
function setHomePage() {

  if ($.cookie('settingOne') == 'jjj')
  {
    $('.secO').css('display', 'block');
    $('.secT').css('display', 'none');

  }

  else if($.cookie('settingOne') == 'ppp')
  {
    $('.secO').css('display', 'none');
    $('.secT').css('display', 'block');
  }

}
```

The function is called on load but not sure if the if statement syntax is correct.

If I alert the cookie setting I can confirm that they are set.

I can view the cookies setting in options->privacy.... etc and cookies are enabled.

If I remove the show and hide code and just add an alert it is not actioned making me believe the issue is with the if statement part.

Has anyone done something similar and confirm if my syntax is correct?

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the code shown. As to whether the code will actually do what you want it to, I couldn't say because you don't show how/when that cookie is *set* and you don't really explain what the code is supposed to do. For readability it would be great to add some indenting.

Comment: @nnnnnn Hi, thanks, I have removed it to reduce the but not amended to reflect real code. No idea why its not working.

Comment: `TypeError: $.cookie is not a function` because jQuery.cookie was not imported => this question will not be useful for other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```js
function setHomePage() {

  if ($.cookie('settingOne') == 'jjj')
  {
    $('.secO').show();
    $('.secT').hide();

  }

  else if ($.cookie('settingOne') == 'ppp')
  {
    $('.secO').hide();
    $('.secT').show();
  }

}
```

Also check if your browser has Cookies enabled.

---

Please give the output for the following:

```
console.log ($.cookie('settingOne') == 'jjj');
console.log ($.cookie('settingOne') == 'ppp');
```

Comment: I have tried this but same result. I can view the cookies setting in options->privacy etc and cookies are enabled. If I remove the show and hide code and just add an alert it is not actioned making me believe the issue is with the if statement.

Comment: @TJ15 Check updated answer and let me know the solution for them?

Comment: In the console I am getting:  TypeError: $.cookie is not a function for both. Thanks

Comment: @TJ15 Did you add the script for jQuery.cookie?

Comment: That's the one, all started to come together with your help. Thank you.